# no output in browser, nothing in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReaactJS, When I check in the browser, I am not getting my Product component. I did not see any error in the console. My index.html and app.js are in the same level. I am using node server to run the app.

My index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Disable browser cache -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Project One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="vendor/babel-core-5.8.25.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main ui text container">
      <h1 class="ui dividing centered header">Popular Products</h1>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My app.js is**

```
const ProductList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className='ui items'>
        <Product />
        Hello, friend! I am a basic React component.
      </div>
    );
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(<ProductList />, document.getElementById('content'));

const Product = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className='item'>
        <div className='image'>
          <img src='images/products/image-aqua.png' />
        </div>
       <div className='middle aligned content'>
        <div className='descriprtion'>
          <a>Fort Knight</a>
          <p>Authentic renaissance actors, delivered in just two weeks.</p>
        </div>
        <div className='extra'>
          <span>Submitted by:</span>
          <img className='ui avatar image' src='images/avatars/daniel.jpg' />
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided enough source code, but this can happen only for two reasons:

## Silencing errors

Somewhere in your `app.js` or `data.js` or somewhere else you are silencing an exception. An example:

```
try {
  // code that is causing an exception
} catch (err) {

}
```

As you can see the error is being silenced in the catch clause. Go through your code and make sure you have never done this. You can simply print the error to the console in the catch clause:

```
console.error(err)
console.trace(err)
```

## An issue with JSX transformer

It is possible that somewhere in your code, your JSX has an issue that stops Babel from finishing the transformer. You can use ESLint with this [plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) to ensure your JSX is valid.

Alternatively, you can also use [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl). I tried your Product component and it seems that it transpires [successfully](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20Product%20%3D%20React.createClass(%7B%0A%20%20render%3A%20function()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20className%3D'item'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20className%3D'image'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D'images%2Fproducts%2Fimage-aqua.png'%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20className%3D'middle%20aligned%20content'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20className%3D'descriprtion'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%3EFort%20Knight%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EAuthentic%20renaissance%20actors%2C%20delivered%20in%20just%20two%20weeks.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20className%3D'extra'%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3ESubmitted%20by%3A%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20className%3D'ui%20avatar%20image'%20src%3D'images%2Favatars%2Fdaniel.jpg'%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B). You need to go through any other JSX code in other parts of your project and ensure it is valid.

Comment: Instead of guessing, why not ask for clarification and more code? Assuming is never a good idea, as you can never be sure and thus, your answer may be useless.

Comment: I edited my answer. As far as I know these types of problems only happens due to error silencing or erroneous JSX that stop babel transformer.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared cache, it's working now. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: So you are sure with accepting the answer? Or is your whole question about some ghost/bogus behavior?